# .NET Regex taking long time to find the match

Tags: c#, regex

Why this innocent looking regex is killing my requests?

```
([\d\w-]+.){6}hi
```

Is this candidate for [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)?

Running this on .NET framework 4.5.2, C#

Comment: Yes, [it might](https://regex101.com/r/juz7Ap/1), what should your `.` match? If a literal dot, escape it.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, got the issue with the regex. should have escaped the dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a literal dot, you must escape it.  If you do not, a quantified group `([\d\w-]+.){6}` will lead to a catastrophic backtracking with longer inputs. Change to `([\w-]+\.){6}hi`.

Note that `[\d\w-]+` matches 1 or more (unknown number) letters, digits, `_` or `-`. A `.` matches any char. When you apply a quantifier, the regex engine tries all possible ways to match a string before it fails. It is usually not a problem with a string where a match is found, it usually happens with strings where the match cannot be found since all possible ways are tried then (until the engine reports a crash).

Besides, the `\d` pattern matches digits, and `\w` matches digits, too, so there is no point using both inside a character class.

Comment: I was not aware that `\w` matches digits too. +1 for this.